# Error 1054: Unknown Column

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `HospitalDB` ;
USE `HospitalDB` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `HospitalDB`.`Doctor`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `HospitalDB`.`Doctor` (
  `D_ID_Card` INT NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Surname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `DOB` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`D_ID_Card`)
);
```

I created all the tables on script a and then used script b to add data.

```
USE HospitalDB;
INSERT INTO Doctor
VALUES
  (1,`Joseph`,`Xerri`,`1994/17/03`),
  (2,`Mark`,`Xerri`,`1978/09/17`),
  (3,`Daniel`,`Borg`,`1967/05/14`),
  (4,`Roger`,`Walters`,`1976/11/12`),
  (5,`Steve`,`Xkembri`,`1968/04/11`);
```

It giving me this error:

```
0   192 11:44:56    
INSERT INTO Doctor
VALUES
  (1,`Joseph`,`Xerri`,`1994/17/03`),
  (2,`Mark`,`Xerri`,`1978/09/17`),
  (3,`Daniel`,`Borg`,`1967/05/14`),
  (4,`Roger`,`Walters`,`1976/11/12`),
  (5,`Steve`,`Xkembri`,`1968/04/11`);
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Joseph' in 'field list'   0.000 sec
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing incorrect?

Comment: your syntax is wrong. Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text values has to be in quotes.

```
INSERT INTO Doctor
VALUES
  (1,'Joseph','Xerri',  '1994/17/03'),
  (2,'Mark',  'Xerri',  '1978/09/17'),
  (3,'Daniel','Borg',   '1967/05/14'),
  (4,'Roger', 'Walters','1976/11/12'),
  (5,'Steve', 'Xkembri','1968/04/11');
```

Comment: @JosephXerri: you used bad quotes (backticks), use exactly the same as I used, so `'`.